# Enable option "Merge Liferay public pages" by default for all users

Tags: liferay, portal

I'd like to know if there is a way to active the option "Merge Liferay public pages" by default for all the portal's user.

This option can be set here (have a look at the screenshot) :
Control panel > Personal site > Site Pages > Public Pages > Advanced.

[image]

I searched the portal properties options but didn't find anything.

If there is a way to set it through a hook, I'm also interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.

I added a bit of code to my AutoLogin hook (see Liferay auto.login.hook property which can be set in the [portail.properties](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/propertiesdoc/portal.properties.html#Auto%20Login) file).

It's easy to set the "merge public page" option with the GroupServiceUtil class :

```
GroupServiceUtil.updateGroup(user.getGroupId(), "mergeGuestPublicPages=true");
```

If a "com.liferay.portal.security.auth.PrincipalException: PermissionChecker not initi
alized" error is raised. It's necessary to first initialize the permission checker. Here is a way to do it:

```
Company company = PortalUtil.getCompany(request);
Role adminRole =  RoleLocalServiceUtil.getRole(company.getCompanyId(),"Administrator");
List<User> adminUsers = UserLocalServiceUtil.getRoleUsers(adminRole.getRoleId());

PrincipalThreadLocal.setName(adminUsers.get(0).getUserId());
try {
    PermissionChecker permissionChecker = PermissionCheckerFactoryUtil.create(adminUsers.get(0));
    PermissionThreadLocal.setPermissionChecker(permissionChecker);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```